# SELECT inside SELECT statement returns 0 count

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by

I have this calendar where there is  a list of events in every day and I use this query to count the events in a particular date. In my database I have `start_time` and `end_time` field where the user have a schedule of materials to be specific. I tried to `select` the events in that day but it seems there's something wrong in my query. Because the user can borrow more than one material so it will be stored in the database with the same `start_time` and `end_time` as well. What I want is to count all the data of the user with the same `start_time` and I tried `GROUP BY` but it seems doesn't work either. Here is my database:

```
    ----Table: schedule----
    id    |   materialID  | borrowerID   | date_reserve | start_time | end_time| 
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    9     |    7          |    bobi      | 2013-08-16   | 07:01:12  |  07:01:12|    
    10    |    10         |    bobi      | 2013-08-16   | 07:01:12  |  07:01:12|
    11    |    12         |    bobi      | 2013-08-16   | 07:01:12  |  07:01:12|
    12    |    7          |    sobi      | 2013-08-18   | 07:01:12  |  07:01:12|
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here is my query:

```
    $cal_data = array();
   for($i=1;$i<=31;$i++)
    {
    $date = "$year-$month-$i";
    $this->db->select('(SELECT COUNT(id) as count_s FROM schedule WHERE date_reserve='.$date.' GROUP BY start_time) as count', FALSE);
    $this->db->select('date_reserve,borrowerID,start_time,end_time');
    $this->db->from('schedule');    
    $this->db->where('date_reserve',"$year-$month-$i"); 
    $this->db->group_by('start_time');
    $query = $this->db->get();

        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {

            $cal_data[$i] = ($row->count > 0) ? $row->count.' ' .'event(s)' : '';
        }
}
```

So the **expected** output with the will be:

```
    count   |   date_reserve    | borrowerID   | start_time  | end_time
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        1      |     2013-08-16     |        bobi       |  07:01:12  | 07:01:12
```

In here there's a big **BUT** where in that query it will give you  this output.
Note: `I'm using CodeIgniter`.
I used `$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);` and try  the date `2013-08-16`(because it is multiple selection)  to MySQL on my server and give me this.

```
    count   |   date_reserve    | borrowerID   | start_time  | end_time
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     NULL   |     2013-08-16     |        bobi       |  07:01:12  | 07:01:12
```

So what do you think the solution for this?

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what you want. Especially I have trouble matching your words with your expected output and your query. Why should the count be 1? Could you please rephrase the question?

Comment: Why 1? Because it is a 1 transaction with the same `start_time`. Sorry for my english BTW

Comment: @fancyPants would you mind? https://chatstep.com/#leonard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
select
count(distinct concat(date_reserve, ' ', start_time)) as my_count,
date_reserve,borrowerID,start_time,end_time
from
schedule
where borrowerID = 'bobi'
```

- see it working in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6b5fed/2/0)

Comment: I cant open the fiddle

Answer (score 1):

Based on fancyPants. Query for CI:

```
$this->db->select('count(distinct concat(date_reserve, " ", start_time)) as my_count)', FALSE);
$this->db->select('date_reserve,borrowerID,start_time,end_time');
```